# Deploying Python Flask web app in ISS Server, but it kept activate the localhost

Tags: python, flask, web, iis-10

Hi I am trying to deploy Python Flask web application using HttpPlatformHandler. When I browser through the website link, it take forever to load the website, so I checked the Python log and it said:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

which I believe that it is running on LocalHost that I dont want to. So after googling some stuff, I specify  the ip address to 0.0.0.0 in `app.run`. Here is the example of my `main.py`

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9090)
```

but the error still remind and the the log file say that:

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:9090/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

The ideal condition is the user will browse through the website link, in my case is: http://<my_server_ip>:8080/ , and the website able to load and display the html page.

This is my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Python\Python39\python.exe"
                  arguments="C:\ModuleTemplete\main.py --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="c:\home\LogFiles\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Not sure what you got from Google, but clearly your `main.py` is the problem, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ For production deployment, you should also use an application server like waitress.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you so much! I am able to solve this problem by using waitress and your info in your blog

Comment: @LexLi I had encounter a new problem, when I click a button that supposes to redirect to another link (http://<myserverIP>:8080/process ), but it said that ```The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.```

It suppose route to ```/process``` which available in my python code and it works when I run in localhost. Do you know what problem might is? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is another question, please open a new thread, and post the question there.